# TypeScript ES dynamic `import()`

Tags: node.js, typescript, ts-node, typescript2.4

While using the new TypeScript feature, so called [ES Dynamic Imports](https://github.com/Microsoft/TypeScript/pull/14774), I am not able to run the code of my isomorphic app on the server side using `ts-node`.

It seems like the error does not occur when using the webpack module loader which transpiles the code in it's own way and running resulting files in a browser.

The error which I've got:

```
case 0: return [4 /*yield*/, import("./component/main")];
                             ^^^^^^
SyntaxError: Unexpected token import
```

Usually TypeScript transpiles the `import` expression to something like that: `Promise.resolve(require("./component/main"))`, but I can't see it there.

How to fix that? Does it have something common with `ts-node`? Or there is a "polyfill" for `node.js`?

My `tsconfig.json` file:

```
{
  "compilerOptions": {
    "declaration": false,
    "emitDecoratorMetadata": true,
    "allowJs": false,
    "experimentalDecorators": true,
    "importHelpers": true,
    "inlineSourceMap": false,
    "inlineSources": false,
    "lib": [
      "DOM",
      "ES5",
      "ES6",
      "ES7"
    ],
    "listFiles": false,
    "module": "commonjs",
    "noEmitOnError": true,
    "noImplicitAny": true,
    "noImplicitReturns": true,
    "noImplicitThis": true,
    "preserveConstEnums": false,
    "pretty": false,
    "removeComments": false,
    "strict": true,
    "target": "es5"
  }
}
```

the code:

```
import * as m from "mithril";

import LayoutComponent from "./component/layout";

const render = (
    layout: m.ComponentTypes<any, any>,
) => ({ tag, attrs }: m.Vnode<any, any>) => m(layout, attrs, m(tag as any, attrs));

export default {
    "/:path...": {
        onmatch: async (args, path) => (await import("./component/main")).default,
        render: render(LayoutComponent),
    },
} as m.RouteDefs;
```

Comment: To get this to work I had to pass the `--compiler` argument explicitly to ts-node. Make it is using the correct version of typescript.

Comment: I'll try that, so it's not using the project's default/installed in node_modules?

Comment: it didn't worked, sorry

Comment: I can't believe noone ever had same error before, maybe something is wrong with my `tsconfig.json`? but I can't find any reference of what options affects dynamic import

Comment: Try running TSC from the command line and see what it outputs. There are a few tsconfig options that would affect Dynamic import but they also would have caused failure when using pre-existing constructs

Comment: it may be obvious but `tsc` compiles to the same as `ts-node` - the error line is still `case 0: return [4 /*yield*/, import("./component/main")];`, what are those options, can I have reference? I have heard that `allowJs` affects that somehow, but I don't know if that's true

Comment: `allowJs` shouldn't affect it - that's just for type checking JS files as well.

Comment: No, as you suspect, it has nothing to do with `--allowJs`. It has to do with `--module` and `--lib` or `--target`. The first affects how all imports are transpiled, and the latter two can affect it because it requires `Promise` for CommonJS support and `--target` implicitly affects `--lib` unless it is explicitly specified.

Comment: @edit - updated by `tsconfig.json`

Comment: `tsc --version` gives you what?

Comment: > tsc "--version"

Version 2.4.2,
> ts-node "--version"

ts-node v3.3.0
node v8.2.1
typescript v2.4.2

Comment: `"lib": ["dom", "esnext"]` would be better. Not saying it's the issue but I advise changing it.

Comment: I compiled [this sample code](https://gist.github.com/MichaelFedora/c3b521845a671d3ef9a7399cd97b2514) fine with ts 2.4.2 and your tsconfig and then running it in node, as well as running it with ts-node. I don't know what's happening... does ./component/main exist? (Note, in the sample code, import *returns a promise*, though it shouldn't throw a syntax error it is important to note!)

Comment: yep, as I wrote - I'm trying to get that isomorphic, so the code already works in the browser with webpack, but not in the node - it's quite confusing, isn't it?

Comment: Are you using local (node_modules) tsc/ts-node or global? Are those local/global versions? If you're running linux, does sudo have different version than your local user? etc. That's the only other things I can think of.

Comment: local, I've pasted versions from the `node_modules` dir, I'm using the `npm` scripts to do tasks so every single time the local versions are used.

Comment: @edit I've pasted the code which is used

Comment: I replicated the error, working on solution now...

Answer (score 8, accepted):

This is a [bug](https://github.com/Microsoft/TypeScript/issues/17060) in the Typescript Compiler which will be fixed in [2.5](https://github.com/Microsoft/TypeScript/milestone/49).

Exporting a default object with a function that imports a file ***will not compile the `import` statement into a `require` statement*** in Typescript 2.4.x.

For example, while this:

```ts
export const sudo = { run() { return import('./test3'); } }
```

Will compile to this:

```js
exports.sudo = { run: function () { return Promise.resolve().then(function () { return require('./test3'); }); } };
```

This:

```ts
export default { run() { return import('./test3'); } }
```

Compiles into this:

```js
exports.default = { run: function () { return import('./test3'); } };
```

Which is obviously wrong. A temporary solution would be this:

```ts
export const sudo = { run() { return import('./test3'); } }

export default sudo;
```

Which compiles (correctly) into this:

```js
exports.sudo = { run: function () { return Promise.resolve().then(function () { return require('./test3'); }); } };
exports.default = exports.sudo;
```

Comment: Okay, so in other words I'm forced to use Promise instead of async/await? `import(...).then((cmp) => cmp.default)` should do the trick, am I correct?

Comment: No; you are forced to export a non-default object, and then export default that object. Async/await will still work (afaik, I can keep trying)

Comment: yep, you are right, I can not use that syntax, thanks for explaining that

Comment: You can still keep the rest of your code the same (using the "default" object, etc), just make sure you are also exporting a sudo-default *first*, and then exporting said sudo-default as the "default" so that it compiles correctly.

Comment: I am on Typescript 2.5.3 (judged from `package.version` and `yarn list`) and the bug is still present.

Comment: Seems to be fixed in [2.6](https://github.com/Microsoft/TypeScript/issues/18968).

Comment: off-topic question, but what’s the difference between `Promise.resolve().then(() => require('./test3'))` and `Promise.resolve(require('./test3'))`?

Comment: the first will run the lambda function when the promise is resolved, the second will run the require function *before* it is resolved, because you are not passing a function there but rather the *result* of the `require()` call.