# Typescript dynamic import

Tags: typescript, typescript-2.5

With the current, latest version of TS (v2.5.x) it is possible to do dynamically import a module using a variable instead of hard coding it?

For example:

```
let modName: string = "myModule";
const myMod = await import(modName);
```

When I use a variable, I get an error "Cannot find module '.'". It looks like the TS is transpiling it to that line of code when I use a variable, so it is irrelevant what I set that variable to.

I have looked at these relevant threads:

[Dynamically import module in TypeScript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18118222/dynamically-import-module-in-typescript?s=2|95.7355)
[TypeScript ES dynamic `import()`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45390721/typescript-es-dynamic-import?s=1|113.3076)

Comment: Have you checked the transpiled code? How does it look? https://www.typescriptlang.org/play/index.html#src=async%20function%20q()%20%7B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20let%20modName%3A%20string%20%3D%20%22myModule%22%3B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20const%20myMod%20%3D%20await%20import(modName)%3B%0D%0A%7D

Comment: Is it a typo that you declare `modName` but use `mod` on the next line?

Comment: This feature is all about working in tandem with your loader. You need a module loader for this to work.

Comment: Yes, it is a typo @zerkms

Comment: The transpiled code looks like this: `Promise.resolve().then(function(){return!function(){var e=new Error('Cannot find module "."');throw e.code="MODULE_NOT_FOUND",e}()})`. I am using WebPack and Uglify, which is why the code looks like this. If I use a hardcoded string: `Promise.resolve().then(function(){return o("my-module-name")})`

Comment: Did you ever find a solution for this or is it simply not possible?

Comment: Sorry of the delay in response. No resolution on this. When you  use a variable name, the transpiler has no clue what you want to load. I ended up putting the typescript in a file and used eval to evaluate it on demand.

Answer (score 2):

You can use eval.

```
function body(theModule:any){
   // do something with the module
}

var moduleName = 'name-of-your-module';
eval (`import('${moduleName}').then(body)`);
```